# Python requests post reponse 400

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have no idea where is error. My response is 400 cuz of it:
`"errors":{"data":["The data field is required."`
but i am sending 'data':

```
data = "{'example': 'example'}"
url = f'http://localhost:5219/myApi'
payload = {'data': str(data).encode('utf-8')}
req = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print(req.content)
```

response

```
b'{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-355ed090aff5fa10460587fe222edbbe-3b3927cf18b26b78-00","errors":{"data":["The data field is required."]}}'
```

how can i repair that?

i tried changing formats and other things but it didn't work pls help me

this is c# code from api:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Bson;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

namespace spyware.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController] 
    public class api : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void GetResponse(string data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data.ToString()));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide the definition of the api. Because 400 means "Bad Request", it means there is something wrong with your request. And the api is not public, which means that no one else can understand this api except you.

Comment: i have added c# code from api into description

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used C# before. But i guess you should use `json="a simple string"` not `data={}`.

Comment: ok i wil try this

Comment: it didn't work :(